# Select from MySQL based on another table's total result of certain column match

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my DB

Genre contains: `id, genre_id`

Music contains: `id, song_id, genre_id`

I want to show the result of:

```
SELECT * FROM Genre WHERE total number of rows in Music 
WHERE Genre.genre_id = Music.genre_id > 4
```

I have been scratching my head for hours trying to get it using `JOIN` but I couldn't get how logically to solve it then put it in mysql code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output is only a couple of minor syntax changes off from a valid query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Genre g
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Music m WHERE g.genre_id = m.genre_id) > 4
```

While that's probably the most understandable way of doing it, a combination of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` may be more efficient:

```
SELECT g.id, g.genre_id
  FROM Genre g
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Music m ON m.genre_id = g.genre_id
 GROUP BY g.id, g.genre_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 4
```